# Are there any tools for migrating old bazel workspace into latest version bazel

Tags: bazel

I have an existing bazel project which can be compiled successfully by bazel v0.5.3. Since the plugin for clion only support bazel 0.24.0+ , I update my bazel into the latest version. However clion tells 
"ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file", when loading the project into clion.

Are there any approach to update old bazel project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) provides a `--strict` and `--migrate` flag that can help you:

```
USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.24.0 bazelisk --strict build //...
```

`--strict` enables all incompatible flags and helps you to identify upgrade problems.

If `--strict` fails you should try `--migrate`. It enables incompatible flags step by step and gives you a report of the incompatible flags that lead to a build problem:

```
USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.24.0 bazelisk --migrate build //...
```

Take also a look at the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.25.0/backward-compatibility.html) about Backward Compatibility:

> When we introduce an incompatible change, we try to make it easier for
>   Bazel users to update their code. We do this by means of migration
>   windows and migration recipes.
>
> Migration window is one or more release of Bazel during which a
>   migration from old functionality to new functionality is possible,
>   according to a migration recipe.
>
> During the migration window, both the old functionality and the new
>   functionality are available in the Bazel release. For every
>   incompatible change, we provide a migration recipe that allows
>   updating the user code (BUILD and .bzl files, as well as any Bazel
>   usage in scripts, usage of Bazel API and so on) in such a way that it
>   works simultaneously without any flags with old and new functionality.